# prime_factorize(1) -> ? (Pythonic error signalling)

Tags: python

I have a `prime_factorize` function that returns a dictionary mapping from prime divisors to their powers. E.g., 50 = 2^1 * 5^2, so `prime_factorize(50)` returns `{2 : 1, 5 : 2}`.

Assuming this is the documented behavior, what would be the least surprising way to signal an error if called 0, 1, or a negative number? Throw `ValueError`? Return something that looks like correct output (e.g., `prime_factorize(-5) -> {-1: 1, 5: 1}`)? return an empty dict?

<sub>And if you have a better format for returning a prime factorization, I'd love to hear that too.</sub>

Comment: I get `0` is incorrect value here, but why `1` is? For `1` empty dict in result is most natural to me.

Comment: I think I'd use a `collections.defaultdict(int)` - that way you can say that the prime factorisation of 50 includes 7 0 times. (`prime_factorize(50)[7] == 0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `prime_factorize(n)`:

```
if n < 2 or not isinstance(n, numbers.Integral):
    raise ValueError("Number to factor can't be less than 2")
else:
    # normal behavior
```

That way users a.) get meaningful info about what went wrong and b.) can handle the exception in a `try...except` block.

I definitely wouldn't turn incorrect data or an empty dict, because that will lead to some tricky debugging the first time someone passes an improper value. Raise exceptions, that's what they're there for!

Comment: I would make it `if isinstance(n, numbers.Integral) and n < 2`, just to be extra specific... on >=2.6

Comment: @TokenMacGuy don't you mean `if isinstance(n, numbers.Integral) or n < 2`?

Comment: Oh, hey, I forgot about ABCs. Thanks. (But you mean `if not isinstance(n, numbers.Integral)` right?)

Comment: you don't even need the 'else' ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using a dictionary here.  Wouldn't a list of 2-tuples work as well?  I.e., have  `prime_factor(50)` return `[(2,1), ((5,2)]`.

Use of a dictionary presupposes that you know the key and want to look up it's value, which doesn't seem to be the case for the prime factors of an arbitrary number.

Comment: Sorry, I should explain that this function was originally written to support a function that gave large rational numbers in lowest terms. That function canceled common prime divisors by subtracting the powers of those divisors in the factorizations of the numerator and denominator. Maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: It's orthogonal to the question, but Don has a point. While factorization can sometimes be useful as a list of pairs and sometimes as a dictionary, it's preferable that a generic function returns the cheapest base representation. If the caller needs the derivated type (a dictionary), he/she can simply write dict(factorization(n))".

Answer (score 0):

More to do with the concept of prime factorization than anything to do with python; factorization should raise an exception for all x < 2 or non integer.

Answer (score 0):

Math functions in the standard library may be a good reference to take as the least surprising behaviour. Let's check `math.sqrt` for example: it returns a `ValueError` on domain error (here n < 1) and a `TypeError` on unexpected type (here if you send a non-integer). So I'd write.

```
if is not isinstance(n, numbers.Integral):
    raise TypeError("an integer is required")
elif n < 1:
    raise ValueError("number to factor can't be less than 1")
...
```

And I agree with Piotr Findeisen, a factorization of 1 as an empty dictionary seems perfectly sound.